# Wordpress blog page title font not appropriate

Tags: wordpress

[Link for blog][1]

In the above Blog page how can i increase font for title of every post?

Answer (score 1):

Add following in style.css. Appearance->Editor->style.css

```
.entry-title
{
font-size:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find Class/ID of element you want to change with tool like Element Inspector of firefox/chrome then add appropriate styling to your element.